# How to add a column to a DataFrame with the mean of a column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is there a better way?

```scala
val mean = df.select(avg("date")).first().getDouble(0)
df.withColumn("mean", lit(mean))
```

I assume that it could worth it to avoid calling an action …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to avoid additional action using `broadcast` with cross product:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast

df.crossJoin(broadcast(df.agg(avg("date"))))
```

or:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)

df.join(broadcast(df.agg(avg("date"))))
```

What you **shouldn't do** is using window functions:

```
df.withColumn("avg", avg("date").over())
```