# How to join a DataFrame with the same aggregated DataFramefor e

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a DataFrame

```
+---+---+----+
| id|  v|date|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  a|   1|
|  2|  a|   2|
|  3|  b|   3|
|  4|  b|   4|
+---+---+----+
```

And we want to add a column with the mean value of date by v

```
+---+---+----+---------+
|  v| id|date|avg(date)|
+---+---+----+---------+
|  a|  1|   1|      1.5|
|  a|  2|   2|      1.5|
|  b|  3|   3|      3.5|
|  b|  4|   4|      3.5|
+---+---+----+---------+
```

Is there a better way (e.g in term of performance) ?

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List((1,"a",1), (2, "a", 2), (3, "b", 3), (4, "b", 4))).toDF("id", "v", "date")
val aggregated = df.groupBy("v").agg(avg("date"))
df.join(aggregated, usingColumn = "v")
```

More precisely, I think this join will trigger a shuffle.

[update] add some precisions because I don't think it's a duplicate. The join has a key in this case.

I may different options to avoid it :

- automatic. Spark has an automaticBroadcastJoin but it requires that Hive metadata had been computed. Right ?
- by using a known partitioner ? If yes, how to do that with DataFrame.
- by forcing a broadcast (leftDF.join(broadcast(rightDF), usingColumn = "v") ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a column to a DataFrame with the mean of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862141/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-dataframe-with-the-mean-of-a-column)